# why image is not rendering when i am including a res.send in next middleware function

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I am newbie to expressjs,
Here is my app js: When i am removing the res.send i.e Aman in next middleware the image is downloading but when i am including that , image is not downloading. I am confused i mean middleware executes one by one , one is executed then next() will evoke and then next but here it is not like that , Why is it so .? Can anyone explain this to me

```
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();

    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.send("Default");
    });

    var Aperson = function(req, res, next) {
        console.log("File is downloaing");
        res.download(__dirname + '/instagram_5.jpg');
        next();
    }
    app.get("/download", [Aperson], function(req, res) {
        res.send("AMan");
    });
    app.use(function(req, res) {
        res.status(404).send("Sorry cant find that");
    });

    app.listen(4000, function() {
        console.log("App started on port 4000");
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `res.download(__dirname + '/instagram_5.jpg')` is async process the `next()` is executed while the `res.download` is working in background.

So you not need to call even `res.send()` and `next()` because after `res.download()` finishes it will respond to the client automatically.

Comment: bas whi toh baat hai.
That if  i am executing that res.download() function it doesn't even matter whether i have written a next function or not, it should terminate in the same line.
But why it is still going to the next controller when i am writing this " res.send("AMan");" otherwise if  a remove this line then image is actually download without any issue.! @ajit jain

Comment: it will go because `next()` statement executed and your code enters in next function while res.download() still in queue waiting to execute it callback after executing `res.send()`   event loop will process callback of `res.download`  that res.send produces `AMan` on screen and close response stream .. you should add following lines in your code and then observe behaviour in console :
use this

Comment: `res.download(__dirname + '/instagram_5.jpg',(err)=>{
            console.log("Async Function");
           
 });`
 instead of `res.download(__dirname + '/instagram_5.jpg')`
2. use `console.log("Anything")`
in 
`app.get("/download", [Aperson], function(req, res) {
        res.send("AMan");
});
 before `res.send()`
@Eddysapata

Answer (score 0):

Use `res.sendFile()` to serve a file from **public** folder

```
/* Public static directory */
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
/* Serve image for example inside the assets folder*/
app.get('/download', function(req, res){       
      res.sendFile('/assets/image.png');      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
/* Public directory */ 
app.use("/images", express.static(__dirname + '/public/images'));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send("Default");
});

var Aperson = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("File is downloaing");
    res.download(__dirname + '/instagram_5.jpg');
    next();
}
app.get('/download', function(req, res, err){
  if (err) {
    return res.send();
  }
  var file = __dirname + '/images/image.png'; //here comes your path 
  var filename = path.basename(file);
  var mimetype = mime.lookup(file);
  res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename);
  res.setHeader('Content-type', mimetype);
  var filestream = fs.createReadStream(file);
  filestream.pipe(res);
});

app.use(function(req, res) {
    res.status(404).send("Sorry cant find that");
});

app.listen(4000, function() {
    console.log("App started on port 4000");
});
```

Comment: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Comment: means you are getting error! You need to return error i will update the code/

Comment: _http_outgoing.js:356
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
    ^

Comment: i am new to this i dont know how to send you the snap of the error here.
https://ibb.co/ji4NnF